# Real Time OBD data between 2 activities Android

Tags: android, android-activity, dictionary

I have been using https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader to use OBD data capture in realtime on the obd activity.

Basically, the information is updated every few seconds on this activity.
All I want is to use this information (fuel level for example) in real time with another activity and update the text not once but in real time.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        drawMyTrack(latitude, longitude, prevLatitude, prevLongitude);
        prevLatitude = latitude;
        prevLongitude = longitude;
        sendLocationDataToWebsite(location);
        text=  currentTrip.getFuelLevel();
        TextView txtChanged = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtChanged.setText(text);
}
```